# How to dynamically load a list of classes?

Tags: php

I would like to load a list of classes dynamically.  The general idea would be to have a sort of manifest/config file that contains an array list of classes and then they would "automatically" be loaded into my application instead of needing to manually do something like

```
use App\Controllers\UserController;
use App\Controllers\ContractController;
use App\Controllers\SubscriptionController;
etc...
```

It seems there must be some way to achieve this as the Laravel framework does something similar with service providers.  You register the classes once in `config/app.php` and then these provider classes are auto loaded onto the app.

Comment: you need to use `autoload` functions (spl register autoload). If you use `composer` in your package, it will configure it automatically, just include `vendor/autoload.php`.

Comment: https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#psr-4 the 3rd example with `"psr-4": { "": "src/" }` is nice. Just install `composer` and run `composer install` or `composer dump` to build the vendor/autoload.php .

Comment: Have a look in the PHP manual at [spl_autoload_register()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php). You do not need `composer` to do this.

Comment: If these are the only files and namespace, spl_autoload_register looks fine to me. Else, use a composer and have the namespaces in `autoload` key of the composer and then run `composer dumpautoload` to load them automatically in your source code. Note that this is different from dependency injection.

Comment: If your are using composer, you will also need to have `require_once vendor/autoload.php` in your `index.php` file.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a native/homemade solution without any PSR0/4 convention or composer package manager, you can consider use [spl_autoload_register](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php) and [__autoload](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.autoload.php) to make your own logic to resolve the classes.

But i would strongly recommend composer and PSR4 standarts for this.

Here is the example of a customer resolver/loader class
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php#102180